# Opening device files on OS X

Tags: c, macos, hfs+

I'm building a file recovery tool and I've encountered a strange problem I can't figure out.

The following code does not fail, but the resulting file size reported by fstat is 0 bytes.

```
    int f = -1;
    f = open("/dev/disk2", O_RDONLY);

     if (f < 0) {
        printf("Unable to open file\n");
        return 1;
     }

     struct stat s = {0};

     if (fstat(f, &s) < 0) {
        printf("Unable to stat\n");
        return 2;
     }

     printf("Size: %lli\n",s.st_size);
```

(I pointed the code to another file to test it and it returned the size correctly.)

However, if I type the following in Terminal it displays the contents of the drive with no problems:

```
cat /dev/disk2
```

I'm running both as root to avoid any permissions issues when testing. The drive is an external HFS volume that is unmounted.

Comment: Have you tested that this code reports a nonzero file size for device files on non-Darwin BSDs or Linux?

Comment: You shouldn't expect `fstat` to return the size of a drive. The [fstat man](http://linux.die.net/man/2/fstat) says: "The st_size field gives the size of the file **(if it is a regular file or a symbolic link)**".

Comment: `cat /dev/disk2`. That is not an apples to apples comparison. `cat` is not just calling `fstat` like you are doing. And it's not even returning the size like you want (it's outputting the content which is different).

Comment: Just to clarify, I don't actually need the size, I was using that to test if it was working. So it seems I can read the contents byte-by-byte until I encounter EOF, but I can't seek inside the file. If I seek to position 1000 from SEEK_SET it returns exactly the same output as if I don't seek at all. Is this normal behavior for device files?